# Better or worse than average for finite numbers n?

Tags: probability

Say you have a counterfeit coin that when flipped it shows **heads** $1/10$ of times and **tails** $9/10$ of the times. As the number of flips grows to infinity, it is true that $1/10$ of the results were **heads** and $9/10$ **tails**. But if we let the number of flips $n$ be a rather small finite number, is it then at any given flip as probable that we would have seen more **tails** than average, as is that we would have seen more **heads** than average? **OR** is it the case that, due to the higher probability of **tails**, we are more likely to see **tails** dominate throughout our flips before the properties of infinity starts to appear for large enough values $n$?

*Note: It would be much appreciated if you would share an rigorous way of thinking about probability with regards to infinity/non-infinity and how they differ, Thanks you.*

Comment: Have you tested this out by looking at small numbers of flips? For example with a single flip you are nine times as likely to have higher than average tails (one with probability $0.9$) as below average tails (none with probability $0.1$).

Comment: @MarkBennet Fair point, but can I generalize and say that at any flip we are 9 times as likely to be above average in tailflips rather than headflips? If so, why is that obvious?

Comment: No - but you can try to see what happens with two or three flips to see if there is a pattern emerging.

Comment: @MarkBennet Will you show how to deduce the next step in the pattern so i can repeat the process :)

Comment: Surely you can compute the probabilities for two or three flips yourself? If you can't I suggest that you are asking a question which is beyond the level of your mathematical development and that you check out the binomial distribution.

Comment: @MarkBennet perhaps you're right, will do some reading and try and answer the question myself.

Answer (score 1):

As $n\to \infty$, law(s) of large numbers applies so heads average is $1/10$.  For a finite $n$, binomial distribution applies so mean number of heads $=p=1/10$ and standard deviation $=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$.